# Confusion about a Markov process

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

The answers says the generator matrix of the Markov process is

$Q(n, n + 1) =150$ for all $n\geq0$;

$Q(n, n-1) = 50n$ for all $n\geq 1$;

$Q(n, n) = 50(n + 3)$ for all $n\geq 0$

While in the problem it says: The raindrops hit the piece of terrain at times of a Poisson process with rate $150$ per second. Independent
of this Poisson process, it takes an exponentially distributed time with mean $20$ millisecond ($0.02$ seconds) for each raindrop to reach the down-pipe. Let $X_t$ be the number of raindrops on the terrain at time $t$,
which have not reached the down-pipe.

So I am not sure why $Q(n, n-1) = 50n$ but not $50$?

I know it takes each drop $0.02$ seconds, but isn't it $Q(3,2) = Q(4,3)$ because the change is one drop anyway?

Also how can you get $Q(n, n) = -50(n + 3)$ for all $n\geq 0$?

Comment: There are some weird characters.  What is supposed to come before $50(n+3)$?

Comment: @NateEldredge It's -50(n+3), so it's negative

Comment: First question: The rate of a transition from $n$ to $n-1$ corresponds to *any* raindrop from a collection of $n$ reaching the downpipe, hence the rate $50n$ and not $50$. Second question: $Q(n,n)=-\sum\limits_{k\ne n}Q(n,k)$, just like in any Markov process.